# SQL query for MIN() of date in future

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need help with a query. I want to group a query by the ID field, and the MIN() of the date field. However, I want the min of all dates in the future.

Would I need a subquery here? The following will exclude all records that don't occur in the future.

```
SELECT CompanyCode, MIN(NextDate) AS NextFollowUpDate
FROM dbo.LeadNote AS LeadNote
GROUP BY CompanyCode
HAVING (MIN(NextDate) > GETDATE())
```

Comment: at least eliminate the `min(nextdate)` from your field list. you'd get all of the matching companycodes, paired up with the one single MIN() date value.

Comment: And you want all records even without occurence in the future? What date do you expect for these?

Comment: @timo.rieber I was just expecting a Null.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a regular where:

```
 SELECT CompanyCode, MIN(NextDate) AS NextFollowUpDate
 FROM dbo.LeadNote AS LeadNote
 WHERE NextDate > GETDATE()
 GROUP BY CompanyCode
```

If you need every company code with nulls for missing items you can do this

```
 SELECT cc.CompanyCode, g.NextFollowUpDate
 FROM 
 (  
   SELECT DISTINCT CompanyCode
   FROM dbo.LeadNote
 ) AS cc
 LEFT JOIN 
 (
   SELECT CompanyCode, MIN(NextDate) AS NextFollowUpDate
   FROM dbo.LeadNote 
   WHERE NextDate > GETDATE()
   GROUP BY CompanyCode
 ) AS g ON cc.CompanyCode = g.CompanyCode
```